# Informix set string column default value to current date

Tags: informix

When creating a table, I would like to set the default value of a char(12) field with todays date. For example, '2016-08-25'

How do I do this in Informix?

Answer (score 3):

If you manage to find the documentation on the [DEFAULT clause of CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0101.htm#ids_sqs_0101), then you'll see that the options for what can be a default value are quite limited.

Further, there are type-based restrictions on what's allowed:

```
CREATE TABLE x(y CHAR(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT TODAY);
```

This generates the semantic error:

```
SQL -591: Invalid default value for column/variable (y).
```

That has the expanded meaning:

> The specified default value is the wrong type or is too long for a column
>   or an SPL-routine variable.
>
> To specify a valid default value for a column, use the DEFAULT clause in a
>   CREATE TABLE statement. To specify a valid default value for a variable in an
>   SPL routine, use the DEFAULT clause in a DEFINE statement.

Basically, you can't create a default of TODAY for a CHAR-type column.

It will be much simpler to use a DATE column (where you can apply the default of TODAY validly), and when necessary, select that value as a string.  There are some minor details like locale and presentation of the data — you might find DATETIME YEAR TO DAY better than DATE because it enforces the ISO 8601-style notation `2016-08-25` for the values.